# block variables not colorized any more in my Vim?

Tags: ruby, vim, color-scheme

Update: Sorry, should have specified --> Vim 8.1.1312.

I've got a new (to me) Macbook, and I'm hacking at some Ruby code with Vim, using my long-time favorite color scheme Wombat: https://github.com/sheerun/vim-wombat-scheme

However, somehow the block variables aren't being colorized. I'm expecting `|val, ii|` to be yellow in color, but no luck:

[image]

Any suggestions ? Thanks !!

Comment: What version of vim? Mac ships with 7.4 i think; homebrew has 8+

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Depends on which version of macOS the OP is using; High Sierra (10.13) already shipped with `vim` 8. Sierra (10.12) may still have shipped `vim` 7.4; I don't recall and I no longer have any machines running earlier versions of macOS to check.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned. 8.1.1312.